# Problema Crear carpetas con python - tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

tengo problema al crear un "n" numero de carpetas con tkinter, La idea es ingresar un numero en el primer Entry y según eso se cree un numero de carpetas pero que se me abra otra ventana para ingresar el nombre, y ese nombre se muestre en el EntryFrame, he intentado varias cosas y no logro guardar en nombre en alguna variable. Su gentil ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto mi avance:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import os
import tkinter as tk 


root = Tk()
root.title("Program")
root.geometry("600x450")



saludo = tk.Label(root,
    text="Ingresa cuantas carpetas vas a crear.." ,
    foreground="black",  # Set the text color to white
    width=40,
    height=10
)
saludo.place(x=55, y=1)
saludo.config(font=('Arial', 16))

datos=IntVar()  #variable de datos capturados

def capturar_num(): #capturar datos

    datos_data = datos.get() #obtener datos y convertir

    numero=int(datos_data)

    #Captura numero de datos
    def hacer_car():
        ruta=""
        carpeta = input("nombre de carpeta: ")
        ruta = os.getcwd() + "\\"
        os.mkdir(ruta+carpeta)

        print("Exito al crear la carpeta: ",carpeta)
        lista_carpeta=[]
        lista_carpeta.append(carpeta)
    
        no_carpeta["text"]=lista_carpeta

    for i in range(numero):
        hacer_car()


txt=Entry(root,textvariable=datos, bd=3)
txt.place(x=230, y=155)

btn=Button(root, text="Guardar", border=2, command=capturar_num)
btn.place(x=260, y=180)

marco_carpeta = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Tus Carpetas")
marco_carpeta.place(height=120, width=400, rely=0.65, relx=0.07)

no_carpeta = ttk.Label(marco_carpeta, text="No hay carpetas")
no_carpeta.place(rely=0, relx=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto quizás te sirva:

```
lista_carpeta = []


def capturar_num():  #capturar datos

    datos_data = datos.get()  #obtener datos y convertir

    numero = int(datos_data)
    if numero == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "El número debe ser mayor que 0")
    else:
        #Captura número de datos
        def hacer_car():
            ruta = ""
            # carpeta = input("nombre de carpeta: ")
            carpeta = askstring('Entry', 'Escriba el nombre de la carpeta')
            try:
                ruta = os.getcwd() + "\\"
                os.mkdir(ruta + carpeta)

                messagebox.showinfo("Acción satisfactoria", "Éxito al crear la carpeta: " + carpeta)
                # print("Exito al crear la carpeta: ", carpeta)

                lista_carpeta.append(carpeta)

                no_carpeta["text"] = lista_carpeta
            except FileExistsError:
                if len(carpeta) == 0 or carpeta.isspace():
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Este campo es obligatorio")
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "La carpeta: " + carpeta + " ya existe en este directorio")
                hacer_car()
            except TypeError:
                pass

        for i in range(numero):
            hacer_car()
        datos.set(0)
```

Se utiliza `askstring` para motstrar la ventana de introducir el nombre de la carpeta, pero puedes crear una ventana personalizada aparte o siguiendo la opción que desees.